# How would I go about parsing this? (Node.js)

Tags: parsing, import.io

{"extractorData":{"url":"http://mobcrush.com","resourceId":"VALUE","data":[{"group":[{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Galadon"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"ShinKaigan"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Minecon2016"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Asater"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"PixieMethod"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"MrSilent"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"MadeMoiselle"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"RohanLive"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"TheRealMcSlushie"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"gibbs"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"karlminer"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"etowah5"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Suha"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"esl_hearthstone"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Feller_Rus"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"『Ｂｅｌ』"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"Tenebray"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"T3x05"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"rikkrollins"}]},{"Userpart value":[{"text":"xwarpewpew"}]}]}]},"pageData":{"resourceId":"VALUE","statusCode":200,"timestamp":1474736137294},"url":"http://mobcrush.com","runtimeConfigId":"VALUE","timestamp":1474736451447,"sequenceNumber":-1}

Answer (score 0):

1) Identify the type of data this is [showing us an example only helps us eliminate what it is not].   Is it JSON?

2)  Get a parser for that kind of data, or build such a parser.  For standard types of data exchange formats like JSON, there are typically parser libraries for major languages already available.    If not, how to build parsers is well understood and you can build such a parser.

[See my SO article on [how to build recursive descent parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769) by hand.]

Comment: I am a complete beginner at this so pretend like your talking to a 5 year old and the data is JSON. Also, I have the JSON paths. Will that help me?

Comment: So first identify the programming language you intend to use, and then go find out what libraries can be used with that language, to see if any of them provide JSON parsing/processing capability.     If you can't execute this advice, you need to learn more about programming with libraries before you try to do this.    If you can execute this, either you will find some useful library or you won't.    If  you do, what is left is a programming problem: use the library element by calling it from your program.   ...

Comment: ... if you can't find a suitable library, then you'll have to build your own parser.   The link I provided gives you about the simplest possible way to build parsers.   Programmers of modest skills can execute the advice there, IMHO.  What we've discussed are pretty basic programming skills.  If you don't have them, you need to study more before you try this; you're not like to have some SO person write a program for you.